# Django IntegrityError - NOT NULL constraint failed: app_comments.author_id

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I'm posting this after trying to find answers from other threads without luck.
Seems like the form is missing some data, which I can't understand why. I'm using `save(commit=False)` also the author has `null=True, blank=True`
Don't know what is `app_comments.author_id` also, I did migrations
my code:

models.py

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
def post_page(request, slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(slug=slug)
    form = CommentForm()
    
    if request.POST:
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid:
            comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            post_id = request.POST.get('post_id')
            post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
    
    if post.view_count is None:
        post.view_count = 1
    else:
        post.view_count = post.view_count + 1 
    post.save()
    
    context = { 'post': post, 'form': form }
    return render(request, 'app/post.html', context)
```

post.html

```
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.content}}
            <div class="grid-3">
                <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{post.id}}">
                {{form.name}}
                {{form.email}}
                {{form.website}}
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary rounded">
                Post comment
            </button>
        </form>
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from app.models import Comments

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comments
        fields = { 'content', 'email', 'name', 'website' }
        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['content'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Type your comment..'
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Email'
        self.fields['name'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Name'
        self.fields['website'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Website (optional)'
```

migrations:

```
# Generated by Django 5.0.1 on 2024-01-20 14:04

import django.db.models.deletion
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app', '0003_post_view_count'),
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Comments',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('content', models.TextField()),
                ('date', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('email', models.EmailField(max_length=200)),
                ('website', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
                ('author', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
                ('post', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='app.post')),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

The error:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\blog\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py, line 105, in _execute
                return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ …
Local vars
Variable    Value
ignored_wrapper_args    
(False,
 {'connection': <DatabaseWrapper vendor='sqlite' alias='default'>,
  'cursor': <django.db.backends.utils.CursorDebugWrapper object at 0x0000015EF21F9940>})
params  
('dsa',
 'asd',
 'asd@gmail.com',
 'dsa',
 '2024-01-21 09:29:17.507631',
 1,
 None)
self    
<django.db.backends.utils.CursorDebugWrapper object at 0x0000015EF21F9940>
sql 
('INSERT INTO "app_comments" ("content", "name", "email", "website", "date", '
 '"post_id", "author_id") VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) RETURNING '
 '"app_comments"."id"')

The above exception (NOT NULL constraint failed: app_comments.author_id) was the direct cause of the following exception:
C:\Users\User\Desktop\blog\env\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py, line 55, in inner
                response = get_response(request)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ …
Local vars
Variable    Value
exc 
IntegrityError('NOT NULL constraint failed: app_comments.author_id')
get_response    
<bound method BaseHandler._get_response of <django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler object at 0x0000027FBF36CC50>>
request 
<WSGIRequest: POST '/post/first'>
```

it seems to fail due to saving with missing data?

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\blog\app\views.py, line 20, in post_page
            comment.save()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ …
Local vars
Variable    Value
comment 
<Comments: Comments object (None)>
comment_form    
<CommentForm bound=True, valid=True, fields=(email;name;website;content)>
form    
<CommentForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(email;name;website;content)>
post    
<Post: Post object (1)>
post_id 
'1'
request 
<WSGIRequest: POST '/post/first'>
slug    
'first'
```

Comment: Do you have any migrations missing either by `makemigrations` or `migrate`

Comment: I did migrations, edited post

Comment: You've not provided author for your comment if you can read the error carefully it's saying `NOT NULL constraint failed: app_comments.author_id` you've to assign author like you've assigned `post` to your comment.

Comment: Do something like this *(I'm assuming author is logged In user)* `comment.author = request.user`

Comment: It seems like your migrations is not properly applied, because for comment model author column is still saying that null is not allowed. So you have double check your migrations.you can try  `python manage.py migrate your_app_name` this command to particularly migrate your comment app migrations.

Comment: It was indeed a problem with migrations, dont know for some reason it doesnt save into the sqlite file